# Scrapy LinkExtractor not able to extracts absolute urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to extract all URLs preset in a page with scrapy LinkExtractor, but it is not extracting absolute URLs.

#### Steps to Reproduce

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

#assume this is from domain http://www.ema.europa.eu
html ="""<html>
<body>
    <a href="/en/veterinary-regulatory/post-authorisation" class="ema-context-banner__link">Post-authorisation</a>
    <a href="https://www.ema.europa.eu/documents/overview/ritonavir-mylan-epar-summary-public_fr.pdf" target="_blank" class="ecl-link ecl-link--ema-obvious ecl-file__translations-title">French</a>
</body>
</html>"""

response = HtmlResponse(url="http://www.ema.europa.eu",body=bytes(html, encoding='utf8'))
le = LinkExtractor()

links = le.extract_links(response)
print(links)
```

**Output:**

```
[Link(url='http://www.ema.europa.eu/en/veterinary-regulatory/post-authorisation', text='Post-authorisation', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

**Expected behavior:**  It is supposed to extract both the URLs

**Actual behavior:** But it does not extract absolute URL

**Reproduces how often:** Every time

#### Versions

```
Scrapy       : 2.0.1
lxml         : 4.5.0.0
libxml2      : 2.9.10
cssselect    : 1.1.0
parsel       : 1.5.2
w3lib        : 1.21.0
Twisted      : 20.3.0
Python       : 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) - [GCC 7.3.0]
pyOpenSSL    : 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020)
cryptography : 2.9
Platform     : Linux-5.3.0-40-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
```

Is there any way to get absolute URLs also?

Comment: here BeautifulSoup's find_all(a) and then ['href'] works better

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it's an absolute link, it's because it contains an extension (.pdf) that's present in `scrapy.linkextractors.IGNORED_EXTENSIONS`. That contains extensions that when followed are going to cause errors with trying to parse the result as HTML for a new response object, so they're excluded by `LinkExtractor` by default. They're things you're more likely to want to use some Downloader Middleware with (file/image) than you want to parse and select from.

The full list (for 2.0.1):

```
IGNORED_EXTENSIONS = [
    # archives
    '7z', '7zip', 'bz2', 'rar', 'tar', 'tar.gz', 'xz', 'zip',

    # images
    'mng', 'pct', 'bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pst', 'psp', 'tif',
    'tiff', 'ai', 'drw', 'dxf', 'eps', 'ps', 'svg', 'cdr', 'ico',

    # audio
    'mp3', 'wma', 'ogg', 'wav', 'ra', 'aac', 'mid', 'au', 'aiff',

    # video
    '3gp', 'asf', 'asx', 'avi', 'mov', 'mp4', 'mpg', 'qt', 'rm', 'swf', 'wmv',
    'm4a', 'm4v', 'flv', 'webm',

    # office suites
    'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'pps', 'doc', 'docx', 'odt', 'ods', 'odg',
    'odp',

    # other
    'css', 'pdf', 'exe', 'bin', 'rss', 'dmg', 'iso', 'apk'
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the information,

'''
from scrapy.linkextractors import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS
CUSTOM_IGNORED_EXTENSIONS = IGNORED_EXTENSIONS.copy()
CUSTOM_IGNORED_EXTENSIONS.remove('pdf')
LinkExtractor(deny_extensions=CUSTOM_IGNORED_EXTENSIONS)
'''

This solved my issue